# restar entre diferentes tablas

Tags: python, odoo

necesito de su ayuda.
Resulta que estoy realizando un sistema de stock, sin embargo logre hacer que aumentara cada vez que ingresara un producto a mi bodega pero no logro hacer que reste cada vez que salga.
Las tablas que trabajo son "producto" y "detalle_documento". en la tabla detalle_documento" tengo un atributo llamado "cantidad_haber" el cual tiene como función agregar la cantidad de producto que saldrá del inventario para posterior ser descontado y también el "cantidad_debe", el cual tiene como función poner la cantidad de producto que ingresan al inventario. El stock final lo tengo en la tabla "producto".

mi código:

```
class Producto(models.Model):

cantidad_disponible=fields.Float(string="Cantidad disponible", compute="_stock")

detalle_documento_ids=fields.One2many(...)

@api.one

@api.depends("detalle_documento_ids")

def _stock(self):

      suma = 0

      for detalle_documento in self.detalle_documento_ids:

          suma+= detalle_documento.cantidad_debe

      self.cantidad_disponible = suma
```

@api.multi

```
  @api.depends("detalle_documento_ids", "producto_ids")

  def _stock(self):

      for detalle_documento in self.detalle_documento_ids:

         self.cantidad_disponible= self.cantidad_disponible - self.cantidad_haber
```

este ultimo método trate que restará lo que ya habia pero me sale error.

Comment: toda ayuda es bien recibida.

Comment: añadi el método intentado pero me aparece un error

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en la línea

```
self.cantidad_disponible= self.cantidad_disponible - self.cantidad_haber
```

pienso que debiera ser sustituida por

```
self.cantidad_disponible= self.cantidad_disponible - **detalle_documento**.cantidad_haber
```

que es donde tienes el atributo **`cantidad_haber`**